Estimating the probability of finding a specific property in a sample
Suppose you examine 1000 randomly selected people in the US to see whether they have a certain characteristic A or not. You find that 15 people have this characteristic. Now you randomly select 20 other people (who were not among the original 1000) from the US. Would it then be a reasonable assumption that the probability of picking one of the 20 people with characteristic A is 15/1000? How would be the probability to have property A if you pick a second person from the 20 people (being only 19 after the first draw). Would it be also 15/1000? Why?

See Standard Error for a discussion of some of the statistics for sampling error.
